# Make portion of OpenGL rendering transparent when using Qt's widget

Tags: windows, qt, opengl-es-2.0, qwidget

I have just started to learn OpenGl. I am using OpenGL to paint onto a Qt Widget. I cannot use QGLWidget because there is a lot of old code that I cannot modify.

I have root widget to which I add two child widgets. One is the widget to which I render directly using OpenGL. The other is a QWebview that shows a simple web page. I have resized the webview such that it is positioned in the center(and below) of the openGL widget. Now, I have added a stencil to the OpenGL rendering to allow a triangle portion to remain vacant. The webview widget sits right below this portion. However, I am unable to make the stenciled area transparent to allow the webview to be visible. It just remains black. See picture.
[image: openGL on QWidget. Center black triange is stenciled area]

Is it even possible to make an area of this widget transparent? If yes, how do I go about doing this?